# Stacking Columns In Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I stack two columns within a column in Bootstrap 3?

I'm not concerned about responsive. This is just for a prototype and I need two divs to stack on top of one another inside a column.

Here's a fiddle. It's the two stacked grey columns on the left: http://jsfiddle.net/frankDraws/6xyqkLgw/7/

Also, I noticed there's padding on either side. How do I get rid of that?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="s2-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, voluptatibus, eius eaque impedit officiis excepturi necessitatibus maiores est distinctio facere. Itaque, id earum accusamus adipisci deserunt veniam porro ab voluptates.</div>
        <div class="s2-bottom">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, beatae, facere numquam recusandae inventore nihil veritatis corrupti quaerat vitae quasi harum in provident ea molestias dolorum nemo magni! Quaerat, officiis.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 ">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, esse neque aspernatur quidem inventore harum totam odit voluptatem impedit doloribus accusantium consequuntur vero possimus dolor quod eius voluptatum numquam perspiciatis.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, at, itaque, nemo nobis nesciunt quidem corporis blanditiis reiciendis mollitia deserunt dolorum odio perspiciatis tempora repudiandae et corrupti impedit ducimus aspernatur?
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.s2-top {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.s2-bottom {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container-fluid .col-lg-3:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: purple;
    height: 400px;

} 
.container-fluid .col-lg-6 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy, but the two gray divs are already stacked. To remove the padding, just set a class on the col-lg-3 div surrounding these two divs and set the padding to 0.

Comment: They're stacking but it's a hack. I was trying to find an better, more "Bootstrappy' solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns are showing up full-width because you’re using `col-lg-3` and the width of the window in jsfiddle is so narrow. Change each `col-lg-3` to `col-xs-3` and you should see columns again.

If you want to remove the padding, add CSS like `.col-xs-3 { padding: 0; }` (but you may want the padding once they're again columns).

http://jsfiddle.net/6xyqkLgw/8/

Comment: That did it! I should've kept trying out the different columns. I tried a few but stayed within `col-md-xx` instead of going to the smaller columns. I had assumed they were too small for the space.

But you proved me wrong.

I appreciate it!